# Create a web screenshot by headless browser in java

Tags: java, headless-browser

I need to implement a function that make a screenshot for a web page in a java backend project. I found some methods like using a headless browser is a good way but none of them performances perfectly (like jbrowser and ashot) for a long page or with too many images. I found that firefox has a function can make a screenshot for me. I wonder is there any java API for this function in headless mode? Or is there any other way to get a better screenshot performance? Thanks a lot

Here is my code to get a screenshot

```
package screenshot;

import com.machinepublishers.jbrowserdriver.JBrowserDriver;
import com.machinepublishers.jbrowserdriver.Settings;
import com.machinepublishers.jbrowserdriver.Timezone;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.AShot;
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.Screenshot;
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.shooting.ShootingStrategies;


import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.*;


public class JbrowserTest {


    public String chekUrl(String str){
        if (str.startsWith("http://") || str.startsWith("https://")) {
            return str;
        }
return str;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        // You can optionally pass a Settings object here,
        // constructed using Settings.Builder
        JBrowserDriver driver = new JBrowserDriver(Settings.builder().
                timezone(Timezone.ASIA_SHANGHAI).screen(new Dimension(1920,1080)).build());
        String url3 = "http://www.google.com";
        // This will block for the page load and any
        // associated AJAX requests
        driver.get(url3);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        // You can get status code unlike other Selenium drivers.
        // It blocks for AJAX requests and page loads after clicks
        // and keyboard events.
        System.out.println(driver.getStatusCode());
        // Returns the page source in its current state, including
        // any DOM updates that occurred after page load
        String string2 = new String(driver.getPageSource().getBytes("utf-8"),"gb2312");
        System.out.println(string2);
        Screenshot screenshot2 = new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(100))
                .takeScreenshot(driver);
        try {
            ImageIO.write(screenshot2.getImage(), "PNG",
                    new File("/Users/*******/Desktop/test2.png"));
            byte[] screenshot = driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
            System.out.println("the bytes" + screenshot.length);
            String filePath = "/Users/*******/Desktop/test.png";
            File file = new File(filePath);
            FileOutputStream fw = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fw.write(screenshot);
            fw.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("error" + ex);
        }
        // Close the browser. Allows this thread to terminate.
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with performance? Is the code taking a long amount of time to take the screenshot? Or is the browser loading the page too slowly? Please explain

Comment: I mean sometimes it will omit some images, sometimes it can not get a whole page if it is too long.

Answer (score 0):

You don't exactly specify your "performance requirement". An easy way to take screenshots by utilizing selenium and chrome drivers:

```
private void loadWebpage(){        
//Init driver
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setHeadless(true);

    options.addArguments("--window-size=1200x600", "--log-level=3");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    //Load your website & wait until loaded with webdriver wait
     takeScreenShot(driver, new File("outputFile.png"))
}

public static void takeScreenshot(WebDriver driver, File screenshotFile) throws 
IOException {
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    Files.copy(scrFile.toPath(), screenshotFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replying, I tried this method but it could not get the whole page screen shot which need to scroll. Another problem is it heavily depend on really chrome browser

Comment: https://github.com/pazone/ashot may help you out.  TakesScreenshot should also be present for firefox.

Comment: I can see my code above and I use this, but sometimes it still can not get the whole page.

Comment: can you give show us the url you want to download the images from?

Comment: You can directly use the url of this stackoverflow page

Comment: I can not get usable results using JBrowserDriver either, but with the headless version of chrome it is working just fine. Sorry, but in this case it's reasonable to switch the driver.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I just tested headless chrome, but it just get the viewed page not the entire page. while I tried ashot+chorme, it still can not get the whole page lack of right part of the page (even I adjusted size with 1920*1080)

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems not to be working: `[1591205742.424][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
[1591205742.424][WARNING]: screenshot failed, retrying timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000` I assume the headless option seems to be a problem here.